# Can I calculate SHAP values on a CatBoost model fit using monotone constraints set to "-1"?

Tags: python, catboost, shap

I fit a CatBoostClassifier model (in Python) with the argument `monotone_constraints` set to a dictionary with values equaling "-1".

However, when I attempt to calculate SHAP values:

```
df_shap_vals = model.get_feature_importance(data=X_pooled,
                                            type='ShapValues',
                                            prettified=False,
                                            thread_count=-1,
                                            verbose=False)
```

I get the error:

```
CatBoostError: c:/program files (x86)/go agent/pipelines/buildmaster/catboost.git/catboost/libs/fstr/shap_values.cpp:810: Cannot calc shap values, model contains non zero approx for zero-weight leaf
```

Note: I have previously been able to calculate SHAP values using the code above when I did not set the `monotone_constraints` argument.

Comment: You're using built in capabilities of `catboost` which doesn't seem to work. You may try `KernelExplainer`, which is supposed to work for any function, or `TreeExplainer` from `shap` package and see if your classifier passes [through the latter].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue using **the old catboost version**.

In **version 0.24.4**, the underlying issue has been fixed, hence my suggestion is to try the mentioned version out.